# Syncing django default/auto-generated id/createdAt/updatedAt fields with prisma schema?

Tags: django, next.js, orm

I have a database which is queried by both a python django app and a nextjs app. I use the Django ORM to maintain the models and migrations, then use `prisma db pull` to pull in the schema from the database to keep nextjs in sync. default/auto fields don't seem to persist over, e.g.

```
# django model, my canonical model definition
class Production(models.Model):
    # production companies that host parties, e.g. Taylorfest
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
# prisma schema, generated from prisma db pull
model party_production {
  id               String             @id @db.Uuid
  created            DateTime             @db.Timestamptz(6)
```

in particular, while the default/auto fields are present on the django model definition, prisma's schema doesn't include the `@default(uuid())` and `@default(now())` upon pulling in the schema.

(I'm using postgres for the database).

do the django defaults happen on the django-side rather than the DB side? Does that mean using django ORM to canonically define schemas is incompatible with other apps that may need to do writes?